# AFNetworking Library - How to pass basic authentication while uploading images?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"..." password:@"..."];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"key": @"value"};

NSData *dataForFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a" ofType:@"jpg"]];

[manager POST:@"https:myURL.php" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    //[formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:dataForFile name:@"a.jpg" fileName:@"a.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:dataForFile name:@"a1.jpg" fileName:@"a1.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:dataForFile name:@"a2.jpg" fileName:@"a2.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:dataForFile name:@"a3.jpg" fileName:@"a3.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:dataForFile name:@"a4.jpg" fileName:@"a4.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpg"];

} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Even after setting the requestSerializer authentication parameters, its not being passed becuase of which unable to upload the images.

has anybody tried to upload the images to authenticated server.

Comment: Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0xcb8a770 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https:myURL.php, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https:myURL.php}

Comment: Oh, you're URL is incorrect! `https:myURL.php` isn't a URL!

Comment: When I am calling this above code with one some images to be uploaded, I couldn't pass the authentication and that is why not able to move ahead for uploading them.

Comment: URL is not incorrect. I just copied a dummy URL as my web service can not be exposed here. I am using proper URL in my Xcode :)

Comment: Put the above error says `NSErrorFailingURLKey=https:myURL.php`?

Comment: @Rich `-1012` is `kCFURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication`, which means that the request must be going through, but failing authentication. I presume Ravi just removed the URL from his code (and comment) for the sake of confidentiality...

Comment: @Rob yeah I finally found the docs for all the error codes!

Comment: @RaviD are you definitly sure the username/password is correct - I can't see anything wrong with the way you are doing the above!

Comment: @RaviD I just tested your code against my server and it worked. Hmm. In addition to checking userid/password, are you sure your server is using "basic" authentication and not another type of authentication?